# Finding Out If a Table is Being Used by a Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

Is there anyway to find out if a particular table is being used by a report on the reporting server?

Comment: You may to query report server metadata to find tables used. Check - (http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Reporting_Services_Meta-data_scripts) and  http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/inside-look-at-reporting-services-meta-data/

Comment: Lazy method: rename the table and try running your report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
USE ReportServer

DECLARE @TEXTTOSEARCH AS VARCHAR(200)
SET @TEXTTOSEARCH = 'urtableorview'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition',
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd)

SELECT name
    , x.value('CommandType[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS CommandType
    , x.value('CommandText[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS CommandText
    , x.value('DataSourceName[1]','VARCHAR(150)') AS DataSource
FROM (SELECT name, 
    CAST(CAST(content AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS reportXML 
    FROM Catalog 
    WHERE content IS NOT NULL AND type != 3) AS a
CROSS APPLY reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query') r(x)
WHERE x.value('CommandType[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') IS NULL
    AND x.value('CommandText[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') LIKE '%' + @TEXTTOSEARCH + '%'
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Works but need correct namespace to be set. I used this answer and dynamically read namespace from Catalog, create a sql in a variable and finally execute it. But the answer helped me to go on.

Answer (score 3):

I found this similar but simpler query on a technet article by Ajit Kumar Thakur  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dbtechresource/2015/04/04/retrieve-ssrs-report-server-database-information/.

```
WITH Reports AS 
(   
  SELECT *
    , CONVERT( VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content)) AS ReportContent
  FROM Catalog
)
SELECT Name, [Path] 
FROM Reports
WHERE ReportContent LIKE '%tablename%';
```

This is very useful when you need "to identify dependency [on] any table, procedure or function in any report. It extracts [the] XML content of each report, converts it to varchar and then search for given object [name].  Catalog table contains XML contents of all RDL files" in your report server.